# Docker Performance Logging (+GPU)

Tags: docker, logging, artificial-intelligence

I am running a few testing of AI application I built, and part of performance testing, I want to record the following:

- RAM / s
- CPU Usage / s
- GPU Usage / s
- GPU RAM / s

There are other which needed to be added from Scripts:

- Inference Speed per Frame OR per Input

Questions:

1. What is the best way to conduct this Logging?
2. Is there other criteria that you would suggest for comparing performance of AI modules? (Inference)